# Products And Order Status Missing In Order Section Backoffice

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Certain orders placed by customer is missing order status (eg: Shipped, Awaiting seller send goods, Payment acceped etc) is missing. It shows blank section in the corresponding column only for certain orders.

When I check the details of these particular orders only sum of order can be found. The detail regarding which all products was ordered is missing from the order details page in the back-end.

I am using prestashop version: 1.6.0.14

Is there any to avoid this issue or recover such orders ? I searched for a solution and I couldn't find the solution.

Please help.

Comment: Is this happening at any particular type order or can you find a condition where this issue is occuring?

Comment: This happens sometimes when the customers use 'paypal' payment method.

Comment: Do you have database access and are you using PayPal's IPN or another method to retrieve orders? If you're using the IPN, I would bet the receivers code is not playing nicely. I don't know prestashop, but that would be my first place to look tracking the bug. If you have database access, compare the raw data produced by the two types of orders; then if you notice what is different, file a bug report/fix it yourself in the short term (the next update will override your changes so it's important you let the community know there is an issue).

Comment: Which Payment gateway are you using?  Plus, upgrade your Prestashop.  There are known bugs in your version regarding orders, stock level updating etc.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Prestashop 1.6.x.x out of the box with trusted modules this problem should never happen.  How to fix:

1. Check all payment modules (credit card, paypal) are up-to-date and are designed for 1.6.x prestashop versions.  Payment modules are responsible for udating order status once payment is validated, so it's highly possible to get the problem here.
2. Check your payment-modules configuration parameters (shop, gateway, IPN, etc...)
3. Clear Prestashop cache.
4. Disable non-core modules and check the problem again. It could be due a 3rd party module.
5. Try to physically delete payment modules (via ssh or ftp) and reinstall them again from scratch.
6. Try to update Prestashop to latest stable release and also each native module.

NOTE: This error has been reported using PS 1.6.x and several modules like "Paypal" or " Universaly Payment Module" with unknown solution till the moment. 
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/459533-order-status-not-added-to-order-also-ordered-products-missing-from-list/
So if it's your case I recomend you to switch to native modules (bankwire, credit card, paypal...) until the problem becomes solved.